# WooCommerce seems to only orderby date and not price

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am loading in variable products via a custom WP_Query

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'product_cat' => 'beast-balls',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'desc'
    );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="product-node cat-beast-balls">
        <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' ); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile;
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

This seems to work fine. However, I am using ajax to reload the products but with a different loop such as this one.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'product_cat' => 'beast-balls',
    'orderby' => 'price',
    'order' => 'asc'
    );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="product-node cat-beast-balls">
        <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' ); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile;
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

I can notice however that between 'asc' and 'desc' the order is flipped, so at least that's working. My problem is that the orderby value seems to make no difference. How can I make it so that the loop changes whether or not the products are ordered by date or price?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'product_cat' => 'beast-balls',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'  => '_price',
    'order' => 'asc'
    );
```

Comment: Yahoo! Worked like a charm! Thank you so much (: I new it was something little

Comment: Any Idea how to sort by most sales? - tried making meta_key => 'total_sales' and it worked (:

Comment: how we can add order by price for variable products?